# How to see if NSFetchedResultsController return nothing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I rewrite my project using NSFetchedResultsController. It almost work. But there is something I want to do which was easy in the prevous code but I don't imagine where to code that.

When the dataSource of my UITableView is empty, I would like add a Subview with a message "To add an object in the TableView, press the + button".

This subview should appears at launch time if there is nothing to display or if the user remove all the object of the TableView.

Is the best place is numberOfRowsInSection (I only have one section), with somethings like

```m
id <NSFetchedResultSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] objectAtIndex:section];

if ([sectionInfo numberOfObjects] == 0)
{
AddSubview
} else {
remove subview if needed
}
...
```

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,
Jacques

Comment: That should work, did you try it?

Comment: Did my answer help you out?

Comment: Martin R. In fact I coded it but don't compile and test it, I need to go back home, I don't have Macs at work ;-) I will give you an update asap.

Comment: Back after doing something else. The solution I expected actually work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a `CoreData` entity called `Countries`. This countries have the attribute `countryName`. To check if there exists an entity of type `Countries`, I call the following method:

```
- (BOOL)countryExistsWithName:(NSString *)countryName{

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Countries"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"countryName == %@, countryName];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (count == NSNotFound) {
        // error
        NSLog(@"error");
        return NO;
    }
    if (count > 0)  {
        // at least one country found
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Edit:
If you don't want to ask for a certain `countryName`, you simply can check for all `Countries`, performing the following fetch:

```
- (NSInteger )countAllCountries{

    // We use an NSPredicate combined with the fetchedResultsController to perform the search
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Countries"];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor    = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"countryName" ascending:YES];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors        = @[sortDescriptor];

          NSError *error;
    NSUInteger count = [self.managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (count == NSNotFound) {
        // error
        NSLog(@"error");
        return 0;
    }
    if (count > 0)  {
        // at least one country found
        return count;
    }

    return count;

}
```

Using this method it should be easy for you to determine if your datasource is emty or not.
Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer will work with an old behaviors. 

With NSFetchedResultsController the dataSource is directly connected to the moc. 

It's not efficient to create method, with the same request as the NSFetchedResultsController request. 

The more efficient way seems to use the NSFectedResultsController